# Prove that $ABCD$ is a trapezoid

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

$ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral inscribed of circle $O$. The tangent line of circle $O$ at $B$ intercepts $CD$ at $K$. The tangent line of circle $O$ at $C$ intercepts $AB$ at $M$.

if $AB = BM$  and $CD=CK$, prove that $ABCD$ is a trapezoid.

I was going down the route of:

$\frac{BM}{\sin \angle BCM} = \frac{BC}{\sin \angle BMC}$, so $BM = \frac{BC \sin \angle BCM}{\sin \angle BMC}$

$\frac{AB}{\sin \angle ACB} = \frac{BC}{\sin \angle BAC}$, so $AB = \frac{BC \sin \angle ACB }{\sin \angle BAC}$

and $\angle BCM = \angle BAC$

$\frac{BM}{AB} = \frac{\sin \angle BCM \sin \angle BAC}{\sin \angle BMC \sin \angle ACB} = 1$

but the relationship is awkward here.

[image]

Comment: Nice problem. What have you found so far?

Comment: @DavidK I added my work above.

Comment: I took back my downvote since you added your work

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $BK$ and $CM$ cross at $P$. If you can prove that $\Delta BPM$ and $\Delta KPC$ are similar, you are done.

Comment: @torontohrb I did downvote it, though, but since they improved their post I took it back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's enough to prove that $BD=AC$.

Observe that, $\triangle BCK\sim \triangle DBK$ and $\triangle CBM\sim \triangle ACM$.

Hence, $\frac{BK}{DK}=\frac{CK}{BK}$

$\Rightarrow  BK=CK\sqrt{2}$

Thereafter, $\frac{BD}{BC}=\frac{BK}{CK}=\sqrt{2}$

Similarly yield $\frac{AC}{BC}=\sqrt{2}$ and thus $BD=BC\sqrt{2}=AC$.

Comment: Why is it enough to show that the diagonals are equal?

Comment: @Allawonder   After proving $BD=AC$,  it can be shown that $\triangle ABD\cong \triangle BAC$.

Comment: Sorry, but how does that show that $ABCD$ is a trapezium.

Comment: Sorry, but how does that show that $ABCD$ is a trapezium.

Comment: @Allawonder   $\triangle ABD\cong \triangle BAC$ means $\angle BAD=\angle ABC$. Since $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $\angle BCD=180-\angle BAD=180-\angle ABC$ and hence $AB\parallel CD$.